# to check if csv file is open from vba

Tags: csv, file, ms-access, vba, export

I want to export table in access to csv file. It works fine if the csv file where I want to export the table is closed. But if the file is open, I get no error and neither the table is exported.
Is there any way to check if the csv file is open already and if possible to close it??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Sub MacroName()
   Dim Path As String
   Path = "C:\test.doc"
   If Not FileLocked(Path) Then
      Documents.Open strFileName
   End If
End Sub

Function FileLocked(Path As String) As Boolean
   On Error Resume Next
      Open strFileName For Binary Access Read Write Lock Read Write As #1
   Close #1
      If Err.Number <> 0 Then
         MsgBox "Error #" & Str(Err.Number) & " - " & Err.Description
      FileLocked = True
      Err.Clear
   End If
End Function
```

Answer (score 2):

Found the solution here. 
VBA Function to Check Whether File or Document Is Open https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/209189

Answer (score -1):

As reported in [this microsoft support page](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/153058), you can check if a file is read-only:

```
Sub Example1()

    ' Test to see if the Read-only attribute was assigned to the file.

    If GetAttr("c:\example.csv") And vbReadOnly Then
        MsgBox "File is Read-only"
    Else
        MsgBox "File is not read-only"
    End If

End Sub
```

If you opened that file, you could always close any file you open.

```
intFile = FreeFile()
Open "c:\example.csv" For Output As #intFile
Write #intFile
Close #intFile
```

If you don't specify the file name in the `Close` statement, you will close all the files that you opened.

If the file is opened by another application, I don't know if there is a way to close it.

Comment: This doesn't let me know if the csv file is open or not.